# Can't adjust redirect in Nginx, for message with code 401 "Auth Required"

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, auth-request

I can't adjust redirect in Nginx virtual hosts config-file,  specifically for "401 error message" (401 Authorization Required).

**My target:** When I open address in web-browser, for example it'll be my.domain.com, I want adjust basic authentication and I wanna get custom html page with original design and original login form instead of simple browser window.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puZDd.png)

So, for this realisation need adjust redirect on 401 message to my custom page. I did try it like this, but it doesn't gave to me any results.

```
error_page 401 /401.html;
        location ~ (401.html)$ {
            alias /var/www/user/data/my.domain.com/www/index.php;
        }
```

I still see window with login form, not own custom page [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puZDd.png)

Full code of Virtual Host:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  my.domain.com;

root   /var/www/user/data/my.domain.com/www;
index  index.html;
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    error_page 401 /401.html;
        location ~ (401.html)$ {
            alias /var/www/user/data/my.domain.com/www/index.php;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I need help with code syntax according to my case, specifically with right redirection code for custom 401 html page with login form placed in this path:

```
/var/www/user/data/my.domain.com/www/index.php;
```

Maybe somebody, could share templates for this redirect in nginx? I don't know yet how to adjust it correctly. Maybe here need to use another nginx module, for example **auth_request** instead of **auth_basic**?

Will be appreciate to workable solutions and hints according this case.